# Develop NAVIGATION transitions similar to tableview transitions in 'Clear' app for a slide in side view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

I've been looking to develop **navigation transitions** that would have a fold or flip feel when traversed from one view to other in a slide in side view controller.

I came up with an open source library on Github:
- https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition

However, it does not accomplish my task as I want to enable the control the transition process. i.e. When a user swipes back and forth to navigate between the main(central) and the side view controller, the same should be replicated in the transition.

In the library mentioned above, I have no control over the transition. It just gets executed on a single click.

I **found an app that does the exact** that I'm looking to achieve. The name is **'Rates'** and is free if you guys could refer it.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks for your time.